# How to change the position while going to a link by # id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change the position while going to a link by `# id`?

Meaning, I have an anchor tag for eg: `<a href="#src">SRC</a>`, so when I click on the tag it displays me like:

[image]

(the div above **Upcoming Quiz**), but I want it as:

[image]

(When I click the link the div above **Upcoming Quiz** is to display!)

I am totally new to it so I don't know how to do that.

Also, I will be helpful if you [visit here](http://jainvidhya.co.in/tindex.php) in small browser width and click on the toggle and go to any one of the links.

Here what I want is that if we click on the link it should go to that div (going) and also collapse that navbar.

For the second question I tried the below code:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#oq" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

Comment: I think there is no way to fix this without JavaScript. Your menu is fixed(I guess) over the content so its height does not count when the anchor position is evaluated. So if you want to make it work you need to use `.offset()` to find offset for your element and `.height()` to find the height of menu, and calculate the proper `.scrollTop()` amount.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code, as I am totally new to that. @Telion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of what you need to do:

```js
 $(function() {
  $("#scrolltoblock").on("click", (e) => {
    let yBlockOffset = $("#scrolltome").offset().top;
    let headerHeight = $(".header").height();
    let margins = parseInt($("#scrolltome").css('margin-top'));
    let totalScroll = yBlockOffset - headerHeight - margins;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: totalScroll
    }, 1000);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
 });
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px; 
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgreen; 
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange; 
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}

#scrolltome {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"><a id="scrolltoblock" href="#scrolltoyellowblock">Find yellow block!</a></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div id="scrolltome"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Probably it isn't any good in views of code structure or general model or flexibility but I think I gave you an understanding of how this works so you could move on with this topic.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, it really helped me, ready to accept this answer. Just [visit here](http://jainvidhya.co.in/tindex.php) in small browser width and go to any one of the links by toggling the menu, you will see some problem. Of course, the problem is related to your answer.

Comment: @JVOQ everything looks good for me. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I clicked the login link, but that div is down, not as it works on wider screens. [See Image](https://imgur.com/a/EpFOH)

Comment: That's because menu height is different when you click in mobile template. You can choose 1 of the options: 1) To set header width BEFORE you click on the link. This way the drop-down mobile version of your menu won't affect the script. To do this you should remove `let headerHeight...` from the event function and move it somewhere to the top of the script like this: `var headerHeight = $(".header").height();`. 2) The other solution is to set height of your menu manually. Usually, noone does it this way just because it is uncomfortable and non-flexible. `let headerHeight = [your height here]`.

Comment: Look at the [javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/6s0dwfm3/) (First 4-5 lines). I did some like this, and now there is now scrolling effect too. Is this the wrong way or I am missing some thing?

Comment: @JVOQ `$(".header")` element was taken from my example. `.header` is the class which is responsible for declaration of the menu in my example. I can guess yours should be `nav`.